# Streaming mp4 videos using exoplayer not working with partial content sent by server

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

I have a server which streams mp4 videos. Whenever it gets a request it parses the range header and sends back the partial content of the video file idenitied by the url as per range header, if the request has no range header then my server sends first 1000000 bytes back to the client. This works perfectly when streaming from browser but when trying to stream on android exoplayer(using `video_player` flutter plugin), an error is raised by exoplayer saying `None of the available extractors could read the stream`. Is there anyway to configure exoplayer so that it handles partial content of the streams sent back by my server.

Comment: Is there a solution for this yet

Answer (score 1):

No. If the client requests the entire file, it expects the entire file with a 200 code. Returning a partial request is an error.

Comment: Is there anyway by which I can configure exoplayer to request partial content?

Comment: It’s open source. You can make it do anything.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation/guide which can help me implement it. I am very much new to android development

Comment: If I was to give you pointers, it would be to change the server to do the correct thing, not change the client to handle the incorrect thing.

Comment: I am trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/TorrentStream/TorrentStream-Android) library on my app with support for seeking. Because the file is being downloaded while playing I do not have the complete video file to send back to client. This is reason why I choose to send partial content. Browsers video player is able to perfectly handle the responses sent back by my server. I would like to implement the same functionality using exoplayer. I am reading exoplayer docs as of now but the documentation is not very clear to me as am a complete beginner

Comment: The server should not choose to send back partial content if it was not requested by the client. The server should only return what the client asks for. If you do not have the entire file yet, you can send what you have via http chunked transfer, while downloading the blocks you're missing.

Comment: @Sundeepbabbur did you solve this issue? I'm running into the same prolem with the video_player plugin

Comment: me into the same problem. sending the whole 200 response file is not good when you have many listeners and many of them just listen to part of the file.